# Coding logic (Python)

Tags: python, function, syntax, logic

I am doing a python course and ran into a problem that has me a bit confused on the logic.
the problem is:

Write a function that takes in a list of integers and returns True if it contains 007 in order:

```
spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5]) --> True
spy_game([1,0,2,4,0,5,7]) --> True
spy_game([1,7,2,0,4,5,0]) --> False
```

Here was my solution:

```
def spy_game(nums):
    code = ["x",0,0,7] #"x" at index 0
    for i in nums:
        if i == code[1]: # check if i matches seq index 1
            code.pop(1) # if True, remove i at seq index 1
    return len(code) == 1
```

However, this solution returned an error message:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-76ad0cd13e33> in <module>
      1 # Check
----> 2 spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5])

<ipython-input-40-54389cdc3f5f> in spy_game(nums)
      2     code = ["x",0,0,7]
      3     for i in nums:
----> 4         if i == code[1]:
      5             code.pop(1)
      6     return len(code) == 1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the "correct" solution:

```
def spy_game(nums):
    code = [0,0,7,"x"] # "x" placed at index 3 instead
    for i in nums:
        if i == code[0]: # check i against sequence index 0
            code.pop(0)
    return len(code) == 1
```

I am having trouble understanding why my original solution failed. Why is index[1] "Out of range" when the list has indexes 0-3? What am I missing in the logic? Can anyone break it down? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would be better off not altering a list while you are iterating through it. That's like trying to replace the wings of the plane you're flying in. Or some other analogy.

Comment: Once you remove all numbers from `code` list, you are left with list `['x']` whose length is one. Then you are trying to access its second element which causes IndexError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write down what happens with `code` after each iteration of `for i in nums`.

You will find that after 0, 0, and 7 have been encountered, `nums` might still not be empty. 0, 0, and 7 will have been popped from `code`, leaving a list of length 1, making `code[1]` throw an IndexError at the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now

Comment: Good! Could you mark the answer as accepted then?

Comment: I did but I get this message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."